# Redirect to 404 if .php extension is requested in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I currently have all my pages working without their .php extensions by using mod_rewrite. Such as:

```
www.mywebsite.com/noextension
```

However, how would I go about redirecting my users to a 404 page if they decide to add the .php extension to the url like this?

```
www.mywebsite.com/noextension.php
```

My htaccess looks like this so far:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(/)?$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^forums/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(/)?$ forums.php?category=$1 [NC]
```

I have tried things such as this `RewriteRule \.php$ - [R=404]`, however, it just 404's every single page I go to. I assume I might have to use something like REQUEST_URI to do what I am asking.

What do you guys suggest I add? Thanks.

Comment: What Apache version do you have?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try these lines (place above those you have already):

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php - [F,L]
```

This rule will block (403 error) direct access to ANY .php file (but will path trough already rewritten URLs, when rule goes to next iteration).

TBH I'm not 100% sure that it will work (it depends on your Apache config) ... but considering that you have v2.2.x it should (it works fine on mine 2.2.17).

---

**UPDATE:**
For *"its kicking my web sites homepage without /index to a 404"* add this line **before** the above rule:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Brilliant mate, however its kicking my web sites homepage without /index to a 404.

Comment: I must say you know your HTACCESS. Thank you very much.

Comment: @SineCosine See my updated answer. Please test all your URLs. The above rule will **unfortunately** block all index files (declared with `DirectoryIndex` directive) when accessing directory (e.g. `http://www.example.com/somefolder/` => `/somefolder/index.php`) as such auto-inserted index.php will be treated as direct access by that rule.

Comment: Yes I understand, I'll simply put these rules in each folder that has a index file. Works beautifully - all urls work correctly even dynamic onces. Once again thanks.

Comment: For index.php in additional subdirectories, try `RewriteRule ^(.+)\/$ $1/index.php [QSA,L]`

Comment: @user883210 Good catch.